# Java Reflect API - isAssignableFrom, Extends/Implements

Tags: java, reflection

In Java Reflect API, in .isAssignableFrom methods in Class has its javadocs saying that it will return true if "the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter".

The question is whether .isAssignableFrom will return true if on a class that implements Interface, or it only returns true when "extends" is used?
In other words, what will happen and why in case:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface{}

MyInterface.isAssignable(MyClass.class) == false/true ?
```

Comment: "or is a superclass *or superinterface of,*"

Comment: Did you try it out with different classes and interfaces to see what happens? Once you have done that, are you able to answer your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `true`.

That are two ways to tell this from the Javadoc:

> the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter

The term *superinterface* is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5) in the Java Language Specification as follows:

> The optional implements clause in a class declaration lists the names of interfaces that are direct superinterfaces of the class being declared.

Therefore, `MyInterface` is a superinterface of `MyClass`, and therefore `MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(MyClass.class)` is true.

The other way to tell is the next paragraph of the javadoc:

> Specifically, this method tests whether the type represented by the
>   specified `Class` parameter can be converted to the type
>   represented by this `Class` object via an identity conversion
>   or via a widening reference conversion. See *The Java Language
>   Specification*, sections 5.1.1 and 5.1.4 , for details.

which matches because

```
MyInterface i = new MyClass();
```

compiles.

Comment: Thank you - this is what I was looking for. I was wondering whether a term "superinterface" will be applied only to an interface that extends another interface although I knew that Interfaces are usually used to instantiate their implementations.